# Why can't it be "If null, wait till not null" rather than the other way

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to to be able to check for null entries into an array, and print a message if they're is empty entries.

Then, when there aren't I want to continue with the program.

I really can't see what I've done wrong.

```
var mainArray:Array = new Array (6);

function addNumbers(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    userNumber1.selectable = false;
    userNumber1.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
    userNumber2.selectable = false;
    userNumber2.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
    userNumber3.selectable = false;
    userNumber3.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
    userNumber4.selectable = false;
    userNumber4.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
    userNumber5.selectable = false;
    userNumber5.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
    userNumber6.selectable = false;
    userNumber6.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;


    mainArray[0] = Number(userNumber1.text);
    mainArray[1] = Number(userNumber2.text);
    mainArray[2] = Number(userNumber3.text);
    mainArray[3] = Number(userNumber4.text);
    mainArray[4] = Number(userNumber5.text);
    mainArray[5] = Number(userNumber6.text);

    noNull();
}

    function noNull()
    {
        var e;
        var noNulls:Boolean = new Boolean();
        noNulls = false;
        for (e = 0; e < 6; e++)
        {
            if (mainArray[e] == null)
            {
                genericText.text = "Make sure all boxes are filled!";
            }
            else
            {
                noNulls = true;
            }

        }

        if (noNulls == true)
        {
            duplicateCheck();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'll give you a hint your array looks like this [a, b, c, null, null, f] - now your generic text will be set to "make sure..." on e=3 but noNulls will be true because last element is not null "f". so either break on first error or make sure noNulls is set to false when null is found

Answer (score 2):

```
    noNulls = true;
    for (e = 0; e < 6; e++)
    {
        if (mainArray[e] == 0)
        {
            genericText.text = "Make sure all boxes are filled!";
            noNulls = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's still not working. I really have no idea why. It just carries on as if there are no empty boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If we don't enter any value in TextField, then "text" property will be empty string, not NULL.

Comment: But I've cast it to a number :/

Comment: I've still tried checking if the array elements contains no characters and it still just carries on :S

Comment: Anyway, Number("") = 0, not NULL. Try to trace mainArray at the beginning of noNull(). I bet you don't find NULLs

Comment: Okay, I traced it and I get 0's, so now I managed to get it to show the message, but it still carries on with the program even if there are nulls?

Comment: If at least one of your textfield is not empty, you set noNulls = true. Try to set noNulls=true at the begining of noNulls() function and change it to noNulls = false in if statement. So, if at least one of your textFields is empty, you will receive noNulls = false at the end of the loop. Check X.L.Ant code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because converting an empty string (in case the textfield is empty) to a number gives "0" and comapring a number "0" to null gives false:

```
 var arr:Array = [];
 arr[0] = Number("");
 trace(arr[0] == null); //false
```

Comparing a Number to null isn't even possible if you type the variable:

```
var x:Number = Number("");
trace(x == null);   //gives a compile error
```

In answer to your comment; You should probably put a break after you set the warning-text:

```
genericText.text = "Make sure all boxes are filled!";
break;
```

Otherwise if the next textfield is filled properly it will override the noNulls value with false again. Also there is no need to check the rest of the fields anyway since one is already invalid.

Comment: Okay, so now I've managed to make it show the message, but it continues with the program anyway? I can't understand why.